# Merge rows in postgresql with dynamic number of rows fitting the merge condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with many records. It has the following structure:

**Table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6):**

```
a b c val1  val2  val3
d e f val4  val5  val6
d e f val7  val8  val9
g h i val10 val11 val12
g h i val13 val14 val15
g h i val16 val17 val18
```

And there are many many more other rows.

As a result I want to have a table:

**Table (col1, col2, col3, col4_1, col4_2, col4_3, col5_1, col5_2, col5_3, col6_1, col6_2, col6_3):**

```
    a b c val1  val2  val3  null  null  null  null  null  null  
    d e f val4  val5  val6  val7  val8  val9  null  null  null      
    g h i val10 val11 val12 val13 val14 val15 val16 val17 val18
```

In words: I have some part of the table which has the same `col1, col2, col3` but different `col4, col5, col6`. Number of rows per the same `col1, col2, col3` varies from 1-3 (it is unknown beforehand).

My idea was to use `GROUP BY`, but how to handle `col4, col5, col6` values which can be met in dynamic amount of rows?

How to make that kind of table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation and `row_number()`:

```
select col1, col2, col3,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then col4 end) as col4_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then col5 end) as col5_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then col6 end) as col6_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then col4 end) as col4_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then col5 end) as col5_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then col6 end) as col6_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then col4 end) as col4_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then col5 end) as col5_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then col6 end) as col6_3
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, col3 order by col1) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by col1, col2, col3
```